# lxml HTMLParser does strip CDATA content while XHTMLParser doesn't

Tags: python, html, xhtml, lxml, cdata

Using lxml-3.6.4, `XHTMLParser` and `HTMLParser` behave different with CDATA tag - `XHTMLParser` does include it in text:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> content = '<div>regular content<![CDATA[, cdata content]]></div>'
>>> html.fragment_fromstring(content, parser=html.XHTMLParser()).text
'regular content, cdata content'
```

and `HTMLParser` does drop it:

```
>>> html.fragment_fromstring(content, parser=html.HTMLParser()).text
'regular content'
```

Why does this happen, and how do I get access to CDATA content with `HTMLParser`?

Comment: `<![CDATA[` is not a HTML construct. It is defined only in XML. (For proof, put a div like that in a HTML file and display it in your browser.) So the parser acts correctly - it treats the whole CDATA block as one erroneous tag, which can be removed without ill effect.

Comment: So possible solutions are 1) get rid of the CDATA block delimiters, or 2) use the XHTMLparser.